# Dual-boot OSx (El Capitan) and Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work after updates Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, refind

I Just Update ubuntu When I turn on the computer usually goes to rEFInd screen, which gives me the option to choose OSx and Ubuntu. Initially, I could click in any of them and they will boot directly to Ubuntu.

Please help ...

Comment: so the issue it that any choice will boot Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the update (re-)installed GRUB, which has overridden rEFInd. This issue is covered in the rEFInd documentation, on the page entitled ["Keeping rEFInd Booting."](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) That page covers several recovery options. Since you don't say to what (if any) OS you can boot right now, I can't be more precise in my answer here. If the system isn't booting at all, then I recommend you download the USB flash drive or CD-R image of rEFInd from [its downloads page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) prepare that boot medium, and use it to boot to OS X or Ubuntu to fix the problem. Alternatively, you may be able to boot into OS X by holding down the Option (or Alt) key while you power on the system, from where you can fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind) to dual boot without rEFInd, David Anderson's answer (btw thanks!). After a kernel-update I needed to do update-grub, and then repeat the process from ElCapitan. This solution needs a grub-install, of course...

Comment: Please include the instructions described on the website linked. The reason for this is because that link could become obsolete and then this answer would be useless. This also makes sure that all of the information is in one place.

Comment: @Owen Hines, I tried to edit the answer but got the _spam and abuse_-message. Don't know how to fix it...

Comment: I just realized that the linked page is another question here. In this case, please post this as a comment on the original question as you're just linking another answer. If it solves the original issue, then this question will likely be marked as a duplicate of the linked one.