# How to change boot order in Mac OS and Ubuntu-Mate 16.04 dual boot from Ubuntu first to OS X first?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, macosx, ubuntu-mate, boot-order

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my late 2011 MBP. The systems were autobooting into one another in an order and when I hold the option key I was unable to see Ubuntu partition.

So I followed this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831161/dual-booting-os-x-or-macos-with-linux-without-refind/838559#838559) to enable booting Ubuntu alongside with OS X on a single internal SSD without rEFInd/rEFIt. Now I am able to see both options when I hold option key.

If I do not press any key upon start up, now Ubuntu boots by default. I would like to make Mac OS X the default and stay able to boot my Ubuntu when I hold "option".

How can I change the order? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To get the option to select which OS boots, when you power the Macbook on, wait for the startup sound and then click on the Option button on your keyboard. (Click this continuously until you see the boot options.)

Select the Mac OS and once this boots up, Click the Apple logo at the top left corner of your screen and the select (System) Preferences... On the Window that opens up, select, Startup Disk. On the next window that opens, select the Mac disk option available and restart. This will load your Mac OS automatically at startup.

Answer (score 0):

It's been five years since this original question, but I just acquired a late 2011 iMac and had similar problems...

In addition to [Jedidiah](https://askubuntu.com/users/839394/jedidiah) 's answer - Another possibility is to change boot order in Linux with efibootmgr.

In terminal write:

```
$ efibootmgr
```

to see current bootloaders, their numeric signs and order.

Then change boot order with

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -o xxxx,yyyy
```

where `xxxx` is boot loader number of MacOS and `yyyy` is boot loader number of Linux OS.

Complete efibootmgr manual page for example in https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Hope this helps someone.

---

**My first problem** was that in Linux Grub I can not change boot option since I only have Apple bluetooth keyboard and bluetooth is only enabled when graphical interface loads. I did not find a solution to my problem.

**Second problem:** Every time I switch between Mac and Linux I have to pair keyboard and trackpad again. It is a slow and annoying process...

Has anyone solved these two problems?