# Installation of 20.04 on late-2011 macbook pro - installer fails to recognize existing OS

Tags: system-installation, uefi, 20.04, mac, macbook-pro

My question is probably implicit in the title, but here's additional details:

- installation target is macbook pro is a late-2011 17" model
- the macbook has a 2TB SSD
- the 2TB SSD has a 750 GB APFS partition with macOS High Sierra installed
- the 2TB SSD has a 1.2 TB FAT partition created to accomodate an Ubuntu installation
- rEFInd has been installed in anticipation of an Ubuntu installation

I've followed the [mac-specific  instructions](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview) for creating a bootable USB drive. From there, I followed the [install Ubuntu desktop tutorial](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#0).

Everything looks good until the installer gets to the "big decision" step: `Installation type`. It reports, "This computer currently has no detected operating systems." Which of course could not be more wrong. This leaves me cold because despite the optimistic assurances on the Ubuntu website that it could be installed on Macs, the installer doesn't even recognize what a macOS looks like on the hdd. This seems **incredible** to me because if I run the `Disks` app in the Live system, it shows an EFI partition, and a 750 GB APFS partition! How could the installer *not* know?

I've tried the "Live Installer", and I've tried installing from the bootable USB drive I made iaw Ubuntu's instructions. Results are the same.

This [curious note was found here:](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

> Most Macs with Intel processors will work with either 64-bit or Mac images. If the 64-bit image doesn't work, try the Mac image.

The *"Mac image"*?!?! After searching for a while, I never found anything labeled a *"Mac image"*  Is this a case of organizational disconnect at Ubuntu, or have I missed the link?

I can't go forward with this installation without some forward visibility. By that I mean, I'm happy to take the "Something Else" route at the `Installation type` screen, but I've got to know that the installer is aware enough not to overwrite my EFI partition - if it even recognizes the mac ***is*** an EFI system!

Is there a reliable and accurate installation guide for Ubuntu on Macs, or enough **current** information somewhere to allow one to proceed with confidence in a manual installation? I've been watching Ubuntu's website for a bit more than a week now, waiting/expecting Ubuntu to post an update to the installer, or the install instructions - but so far, it seems they are either unaware, or ???

Comment: The *"Mac image"*???  Could you possibly be referring to legacy versions of Ubuntu that offered an BIOS booting installation which using the GUID Partition Table (GPT)? This was reserved for the initial 64 bit intel Macs with 32 bit EFI's. This type of installation allowed a 64 bit Ubuntu to operate; even though OS X could only be installed as a 32 bit operating system. A 2017 Mac does not have a BIOS.

Comment: Is macOS installed in a APFS container? I would assume so, because you have installed High Sierra to a SSD.  Most likely the Ubuntu installer does not recognize APFS. This really should not be an issue, since Ubuntu can be booted using the Mac Startup Manager that exists in the firmware on the logic board.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: The "Mac image" was named [here](https://imgur.com/n76q3T9) on this [page on Ubuntu's website](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Yes - a "container" :-/  You may be right that the installer doesn't recognize it, but the live system certainly does - I looked at it while using the live system on the Macbook. And surprisingly (to me anyway) mac's `Startup Manager` will give you the choice without using `rEFInd`. However, as RodSmith explained in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/832609/831935), it comes down to a choice between `rEFInd` and `grub`. So it seems that mac's `Startup Manager` can't do everything required to boot Linux on a mac - do you agree??

Comment: The live system can not read volumes stored in APFS containers. [Here is the error message I received when trying to do so.](https://imgur.com/a/VON4djh)

Comment: The is no choice between `rEFInd` and `GRUB`. You can boot `GRUB` with or without `rEFInd`. You can boot `Ubuntu` with or without `GRUB`. You can boot `Ubuntu` with or without `rEFInd`. You can boot `GRUB` with or without the Mac Startup Manager. You can boot `rEFInd` with out with out the Mac Startup Manager. You can boot `Ubuntu` with or without Mac Startup Manager. I probably missed a few, but you should get the idea. There are many combinations which can be used to boot Ubuntu on a Mac. You seems to have found a way to miss all of them.

Comment: An Mac image ISO (probably the last) that can be downloaded is named [`ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso`](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/14.04.5/). This usesa a BIOS booting GRUB and the GPT instead of the MBR partition table. You would have to attempt to install updates to get to the current Ubuntu.

Comment: I should point out that macOS is not installed in the EFI partition and does not boot from the EFI partition on your Mac.

Comment: Under Installation type, you should choose `something else`. The instructions provided by Ubuntu do not explain the steps that need to be preformed under the something else option. The simplest option is to create a ext4 partition with the mount point `/`. The assumption is that you first used macOS to create space before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: If you install using the Mac image then `something else` is complicated by needing a partition for the GRUB files hat normally exist where the GPT is stored. Also you will probably need a swap partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: (1) It may not read them, but it recognizes them as APFS partitions. (2) Take up your diff w/ Rod Smith please - 4th P [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/832609/831935) (3) Ah! - OK, but Mac isn't BIOS system, but that solves the *mystery* - Thnx (4) Interesting! in my EFI partition, there is one folder: `APPLE`; wonder what it is? (5) Yes - in my case I created a huge FAT partition as I thought Ubu would need it. When it saw "nothing" I got nervous :)  (6) Mac image?! I'm unclear on utility of that given vintage & need for 6 updates to get to 20.04. `ubiquity -b`=no grub?

Comment: Where are you with installing Ubuntu? Where are you stuck and need help?

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Thanks for asking. I'm *creeping* slowly along, taking notes and researching items that come up. If you'd care to participate in the [chat session](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108887/discussion-between-japhwil-and-david-anderson), that may be v. helpful.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: Just cleaning up after my (finally) successful Ubuntu install. If you'd like the points, please prepare an answer to this Q I can accept - it doesn't need to be as long as our [chat session was](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108887/discussion-between-japhwil-and-david-anderson). :)